# Fill the Widget by image, of which resolution is different

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a picture 640 * 400

For example if the mobile phone resolution is 1280 * 960

```
Widget background = new Positioned.fill(
    child: Image.asset('images/back.png'),
    right: 0,
    left: 0
);
```

the picture is magnified to 640x400 -> 1280x800.

so there appears blank in the screen.

But in this case, I want to magnify to the 1536x960,

It can fill the screen without blank.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `fit` property of the `Image` to `BoxFit.cover`:

```
Positioned.fill(
    child: Image.asset('images/back.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
    right: 0,
    left: 0
);
```

Comment: `BoxFit.contain` dose not work for me but I changed `BoxFit.cover` works.